# Install numpy silently from command line (batch file)

Tags: python, numpy, silent-installer

I am trying to install numpy silently from the command line. 

I have a custom python33 installed on the system which does not have the easy_install and pip module and there seem to be no other option to proceed with numpy installation.

Also, i have to be able to do this without using any third party tools.
I can only use command line, powershell or python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have auxilliary tools to install some package, you have to build it from sources.

The usual workflow: download archive with sources, unpack and install.

See [**this link (official instructions for Windows/Linux/Mac OS)**](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/index.html),
and also [*here, section "Basic installation"*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html)

Comment: Thanks. I looked up the option but this is not something I can use. I am required to use a controlled installation file and cannot use anything else to enhance the process. With all those restrictions in place I opted for a manual UI based installation :(

Comment: @pbaral UI installation - not that bad too! :)